# Node JS Sequelize, How to sync changes models on migrations

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

i am using sequelize cli, when i am created a model then migrations automatically created, but when i made changes on my model,then migrations can't automatically updated,so whether we can synchronize the changes that occur in the model to migration ?

thanks so much

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your problem? Perhaps show some of your code!

Comment: its okay, the problem has been solved thanks @ThomasW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write migrations for all the changes.
Sequelize cli provides operation like 
`db:migrate:create`.

You can refer the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html) for more info